# How to use ng-repeat in multiple div's?

Tags: angularjs

I am working with angularJS ng-repeat. So, I want to use my ng-repeat value in another div. I am doing the following. But it doesn't loop through and give me the exact value.

**Code in ng-repeat**

```
<div uib-slide index="$index" class="uibSlider" ng-repeat='id in code' ng-click="$parent.ContentId = id.ContentId" ng-class="{'selected' : ContentId.Id === ContentId}">
  <paragraph tag>{{id.ContentId}}</paragraph tag>
</div>
```

**Code in Another Div**

```
<div>
  <label>{{(code| filter: {Id: ContentId}: true)[1].ContentId}}</label>
</div>
```

So, the problem is I have bunch of data and in the another div if I make the array value from 0 to 1. i'm getting null value. But automatically the value isn't changing based on what I contentID select. It always gives me the same value. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat-start | ng-repeat-end

```
<div uib-slide ng-repeat-start='id in code'>
  <paragraph tag>{{id.ContentId}}</paragraph tag>
</div>
<div ng-repeat-end>
  <label>{{(id.ContentId}}</label>
</div>
```

If you are trying to show the same data in a modal, depending where the user clicks:

```
<div ng-repeat="id in code">
  <!-- when the user clicks here, the modal will open. The ID will be the same as the one clicking -->

  <a ng-click="openModal(id)">Open modal for id: {{id}}</a>
</div>
```

Then in your controller you will have a function called openModal which takes a parameter (id) that will open the modal and pass along the data.

Comment: ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat end is not working. it always say that ng-repeat-start doesn't have ng-repeat end. Even though I keep it.

Comment: I did as you did and It works partially. It updates the value only for the first time. when I check for the other Id the is the value of the id remains the same.

Comment: If I reload the page it says that the Id is undefined

Comment: Oh! Okay i hope it would work hanging around with this issue from a long time at least with your help its working partially. :)

Comment: I'm still unable to get the id of the selected content.

Comment: Yeah!So, now this works inside a carousal perfectly. But The thing is that on a carousal I have a angular js modal dialog box where I want to call this content ID. So, the id doesn't get updated in the modal dialog box it only gets the first value.

Comment: But how many IDs are you having in your modal dialog? Why don't you just do two ng-repeats separately?

Comment: My main motive is when user click the modal dialog, on the modal dialog it should show the same content ID. Yeah I actually tried to keep to ng-repeats but by doing so when I click the get modal button I'm getting two modal dialogs insted of 1.

Comment: Then you are going about it the wrong way. Let me update my answer

Comment: Yeah May be I think so I'm new to angular JS.

Comment: Check my answer now. Are you using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal this?

Comment: Yes i'm using Angular-ui bootstrap

Comment: Ok, check my answer, read the documentation and check the examples. You can pass data to the modal.

Comment: I saw your answer I need one clarification, where should i use ** <a ng-click="openModal(id)">Open modal for id: {{id}}</a>**  inside the modal dialog or inside the the button which gets the modal? And openModal is a predefined function or I need to define it?

Comment: I tried your suggestion now it says that the id is undefined.

Comment: You need to define it, same way as the docs (check link). You would use the  link inside your ng-repeat so each item in your array will open the modal with different data

Comment: I'm really sorry I did not see that you wanted me to create a function which opens a dialog.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/H5jzbUArIdH8kdGKdPCu?p=preview Here you have an example that does what I understand you want to do. Anyway, its all in the docs, read up!

Comment: Yup This looks great, and I just saw documentation, hopefully this time it should work.

Comment: Awesome! Your suggestion works, I'm able to bind the id with this. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it.